# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in file location

Tags: php

I am creating an object oriented login and this is my database  class page.

```
 <?php
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error= false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;






    public function _construct(){
            try{
                $this->_pdo = new 
        PDO('mysql:host='.Config::get('mysql/host').'
         ;dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db')

            Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'));
                echo 'Connected';
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());

            }

    }

    public static function getInstance(){
            if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
                self::$_instance = new DB();

            }
            return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params =array()){
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query=$this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
            echo 'Success';
        }  


    }

}


?>
```

This is my index page which I am using to test the ability of the program to accept queries. I get this error when I try to run this page

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\objectorientedlogin\classes\DB.php:36 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\objectorientedlogin\index.php(4): DB->query('SELECT username...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\objectorientedlogin\classes\DB.php on line 36

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT username FROM users");
?>
```

This is my init.php page which has an autoloader for loading each class.

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config']= array(
'mysql'=> array(
    'host'=>'127.0.0.1',
    'username'=> 'root',
    'password'=>'',
    'db'=>'oop_login'
    ),
'remember'=>array(
    'cookie_name'=>'hash',
    'cookie_expiry'=>604800
    ),
'session'=> array(
    'session_name'=> 'user'
    ),

);

  spl_autoload_register(function($class){

require_once 'classes/'.$class.'.php';
});

  require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';



?>
```

This is my configuration page

```
<?php
 Class Config{

 public static function get($path=null){
    if($path){
        $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
        $path = explode('/',$path);

        foreach($path as $bit){
            if(isset($config[$bit])){
                $config = $config[$bit];
            }
        }
        return $config;

    }

}

}

?>
```

Comment: Because, it's a typo `_construct` - missing an underscore => `__construct`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a typo with `_construct`. It should be `__construct`

```
public function __construct(){

}
```